# Why is the number 1 always generated for variables where another number should be generated

Tags: java, cryptography

I am developing an anonymous voting system. At the beginning of the voting, the server generates common data according to the RSA system. Two secret large unequal primes P,Q,P≠Q are formed. The number N=PQ known to all participants is calculated. In addition, the server generates a secret key C and a public key D, related by the relation CD mod ϕ(N)=1, where ϕ(N)=(P-1)(Q-1). Obviously, in this case both keys must be coprime to ϕ(N).

So, why do I always generate numbers C, D = 1?

```
Random random = new Random();

BigInteger P,Q,N,C,D,f;

do {
    P = new BigInteger(32, random);
    Q = new BigInteger(32, random);
} while (P.equals(Q));

N = P.multiply(Q);
f = (P.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).multiply(Q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
BigInteger gcd;
do {
    D = genCoPrime(f, 16);
    C = D.modInverse(f);
    gcd = (C.multiply(D)).gcd(f);
} while (gcd.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0 || C.compareTo(P) > 0 || D.compareTo(P) > 0);

public static BigInteger genCoPrime(BigInteger value, int numBits) {
    BigInteger coPrime;

    do{
        coPrime = new BigInteger(numBits, new Random());
    } while ((value.gcd(coPrime)).compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0);
    return coPrime;
}
```

Comment: If you want two, coPrime values, why not just generate two large values and divide each by the GCD?

Comment: You can't.  I misunderstood part of your question.  What is the immediate problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, can you please show me with my example? I will generate numbers P, Q up to a length of 1024

Comment: My problem is that the numbers C,D are always 1, although I'm sure there must be other numbers

Comment: `new BigInteger(int,Random)` does NOT generate primes; to get probable primes use `new BigInteger(int,int,Random)` or call `isProbablePrime(int)` and reject those which return false. Also, the standard notation for RSA uses 'e' for public exponent and 'd' for private; if you talk to a cryptographer and say 'd' is public they'll think you're insane. And it's sufficient for them to be inverses modulo lambda not phi, but they don't need to be <= p (or q) and usually d won't be. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_generation .

Comment: And finally if n is public (as is usual) and only 63-64 bits, it can be factored in seconds and your system is broken. You need p,q at least 512 bits, and that's borderline; nearly all real systems that use RSA (such as for example HTTPS on this website) since about 2010 require at least 1024 bits per factor (which Java can do just fine).

Comment: In addition to @dave_thompson_085 correct observations, there are other problems. You want to choose D randomly in [2, ϕ(N)], not randomly in [2, sqrt(ϕ(N)] (really should use λ(N)). You should use `SecureRandom` instead of `Random`, and not create a new instance every time through the loop in `genCoPrime`. Once you've D coprime to ϕ(N) its inverse C is guaranteed to be coprime to ϕ(N), so there's no need for the loop.